# Named arguments in ES2015 (or later)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

ES2015 introduced [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). In other languages with default parameters, they can also usually be named in function calls, to make them more useful when there is more than one:

```
function foo(baz = 0, bar = 1) { ... }

foo(bar = 3); // baz should be 0
```

ES2015 doesn't seem to have added this (I'll be happy to learn if I missed it or if a later version does).

There is the old approach of passing an object instead:

```
function foo(options) { 
  baz = options.baz || 0;
  bar = options.bar || 1;
}

foo({bar: 3}); // baz is 0
```

What I am looking for is a way to combine them, so I could call either

```
foo(5) // baz = 5, bar = 1
foo({baz: 5}) // baz = 5, bar = 1
foo({bar: 3}); // baz = 0, bar = 3
foo(5, {bar: 3}); // baz = 5, bar = 3
```

emulating named arguments from other languages.

Comment: That is probably possible for some functions where you can determine from the type what the intent would be, but it may involve a lot of boilerplate checking code and is probably not worth it overall.

Comment: @Ele I don't think you understood the question. _If_ JS had named arguments, it would be 0, but it doesn't. I edited to make it more clear.

Comment: Now your question makes sense with that last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *partially* achieved by using object destructuring on input parameters:

```js
// The object being passed is also optional.
// - If you call the function with no parameter, 
//   it'll be set an empty object so you'll get the default one
// - If you give an object with any of the properties already set
//   you either get these values or one of the defaults
const f = ( { x = 11, y = 10 } = {} ) => {
  console.log( `${x} ${y}` )
}

f( { y: 20 } )
```

BTW, you can combine regular parameters with destructured ones, but you can't provide destructurable arguments as if they were regular parameters:

- `f( 1, { y: 10 } )` won't assign `x`.
- `f( { x: 10 }, 2 )` won't assign `y`.

In addition, you can accept regular and destructured parameters:

```js
const f = ( w, { x = 1, y = 2 } = {}, z = 3 ) => 
      console.log( `${w} ${x} ${y} ${z}` )

f( 80, { y: 35 } )
```

You're forced to give *argument maps* (i.e. objects). BTW, if you get used with this approach, you almost get the same functionality, excepting the ability to give unnamed positional arguments.

Comment: I do not think that addresses the question.

Comment: @H.B. I can expand it

Comment: This is a very nice simplification of "the old approach", but doesn't allow passing part of parameters by position, which is what I asked about.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Now I believe my expanded explanation gives enough insights to realize that ES2017-2017-2018 doesn't provide that feature at all, but if you use destructuring you can get it, am I mistaken?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Your edit seems to be incomplete.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer It ends in "you almost". You almost what?

Answer (score 1):

Can be made to work in this instance, but probably not worth it. Use Matías Fidemraizer's approach.

```js
const foo = (arg1, arg2) =>
{
   let args = { baz: 0 , bar: 1 };
   if (typeof arg1 == 'number')
      args.baz = arg1;
   else
      Object.assign(args, arg1);
   if (typeof arg2 == 'number')
      args.bar = arg2;
   else
      Object.assign(args, arg2);
      
   console.log(args);
}

foo(5) // baz = 5, bar = 1
foo({baz: 5}) // baz = 5, bar = 1
foo({bar: 3}); // baz = 0, bar = 3
foo(5, {bar: 3}); // baz = 5, bar = 3
```